# problem with typescript it doesn't let me put the prop in react and zustand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zustand

```js
interface ArticuloCompra {
  id: string;
  cantidad: number;
  titulo: string;
  precio: number;
  descuento: number;
  descripcion: string;
  imagen: string;
}

const enviarComprasUsuarios = ({
  grupos,
}: {
  grupos: { [key: string]: ArticuloCompra & { cantidad: number } };
}) => {
  // Assuming "usuario" and "precioTotal" are defined somewhere
  if (usuario.dinero >= precioTotal) {
    Object.values(grupos).forEach(
      (itemCompras: ArticuloCompra & { cantidad: number }) => {
        const { item, cantidad } = itemCompras;
        const { id } = item;
        const nuevoDinero = usuario.dinero - precioTotal * cantidad;

        console.log(id);

        // Adjust this line according to your store structure
        agregarComprasUsuarios(usuario.id, item);
        quitarArticulo(id); // Uncomment this line if needed
        setNDinero(nuevoDinero);
        actualizarDineroUsuario(usuario.id, nuevoDinero);
        rutaNavegacion("/compras/comprasCompradas/");
      }
    );
  }
};
```

in `const { item } = itemCompras;` it gives me this error:

```
Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ArticuloCompra & { cantidad: number; }'.ts(2339)
```

this is the store:

```js
export interface ArticuloCompra {
  readonly id: string;
  cantidad: number;
  titulo: string;
  precio: number;
  descuento: number;
  descripcion: string;
  imagen: string;
}

export interface Usuarios {
  readonly id: string;
  usuario: string;
  contraseña: string;
  dinero: number;
  imagen: string;
  edad: number;
  articulosComprados: ArticuloCompra[];
}

interface DatosUsuarios {
  usuarios: Usuarios[];
  agregarComprasUsuarios: (usuarioId: string, item: ArticuloCompra) => void;
  actualizarDineroUsuario: (usuarioId: string, nuevoDinero: number) => void;
}

export const usuariosDatos = create<DatosUsuarios>((set) => ({
  usuarios: [
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      usuario: "hernan",
      contraseña: "mariela123",
      dinero: 300000000,
      edad: 23,
      articulosComprados: [],
      imagen: imagenHernan,
    },
  ],
  agregarComprasUsuarios: (usuarioId, item) =>
    set((state) => {
      const usuariosActualizados = state.usuarios.map((usuario) =>
        usuario.id === usuarioId
          ? {
              ...usuario,
              articulosComprados: [...usuario.articulosComprados, item],
            }
          : usuario
      );
      return { usuarios: usuariosActualizados };
    }),
  actualizarDineroUsuario: (usuarioId, nuevoDinero) =>
    set((state) => {
      const usuariosActualizados = state.usuarios.map((usuario) =>
        usuario.id === usuarioId ? { ...usuario, dinero: nuevoDinero } : usuario
      );
      return { usuarios: usuariosActualizados };
    }),
}));
```

These are the data that the item contains:

```
cantidad    : 1
descripcion : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
descuento   : 30
id          : "dJt9GJt8_z92X9xbclVoY"
imagen      : "/src/assets/imagenes/pantalones/pantalon_verde.jpg"
precio      : 20000
titulo      : "pantalon verde"
```

I need to be able to pass the correct props to item to be able to correct the error:

```
Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ArticuloCompra & { cantidad: number; }'.ts(2339)
⚠ Error (TS2339)  | 
`Property item does not exist on type ArticuloCompra & {cantidad: number}
 .
const item: any
```

Comment: The error pretty much word for word explains the problem. Your `ArticuloCompra` does not _have_ an `item` property defined, so you can't just deference that and expect TS not to throw an error. Either add it to your `ArticuloCompra` interface, or don't claim `itemCompras: ArticuloCompra` (but really, the former: if your object implements an interface, and that object can have a property called `item`, your interface should have a property called `item`, too).

Answer (score 0):

You have all the properties you need in `ArticuloCompra`:

```
(itemCompras: ArticuloCompra => {
        // Assuming that cantidad (quantity) was already setted. 
        const { id } = itemCompras;
        console.log(id);
        ...
        // See interface DatosUsuarios
        agregarComprasUsuarios(usuario.id, itemCompras);
        ...
)
```